# Is there a recursive version of the dict.get() built-in?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have a nested dictionary object and I want to be able to retrieve values of keys with an arbitrary depth.  I'm able to do this by subclassing `dict`:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def recursive_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         default = kwargs.get('default')
...         cursor = self
...         for a in args:
...             if cursor is default: break
...             cursor = cursor.get(a, default)
...         return cursor
... 
>>> d = MyDict(foo={'bar': 'baz'})
>>> d
{'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}
>>> d.get('foo')
{'bar': 'baz'}
>>> d.recursive_get('foo')
{'bar': 'baz'}
>>> d.recursive_get('foo', 'bar')
'baz'
>>> d.recursive_get('bogus key', default='nonexistent key')
'nonexistent key'
```

However, I don't want to have to subclass `dict` to get this behavior.  Is there some built-in method that has equivalent or similar behavior?  If not, are there any standard or external modules that provide this behavior?

I'm using Python 2.7 at the moment, though I would be curious to hear about 3.x solutions as well.

Comment: d.get('foo').get('bar') ?

Comment: It sounds like you're reasonably happy with the functionality you've achieved using the code posted in your question.  Is there any particular reason you don't want to subclass `dict`?

Comment: @Foon, that doesn't nest to an arbitrary depth and it will throw an exception (instead of returning the default value) if some key early in the chain doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnY - Just a couple reasons - I'm hoping there's some method to do this on dict objects without coercing them into MyDict objects, and I'm curious if this is possible without subclassing dict. Otherwise, subclassing works just fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A very common pattern to do this is to use an empty dict as your default:

```
d.get('foo', {}).get('bar')
```

If you have more than a couple of keys, you could use `reduce` (note that in Python 3 `reduce` must be imported: `from functools import reduce`) to apply the operation multiple times

```
reduce(lambda c, k: c.get(k, {}), ['foo', 'bar'], d)
```

Of course, you should consider wrapping this into a function (or a method):

```
def recursive_get(d, *keys):
    return reduce(lambda c, k: c.get(k, {}), keys, d)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there was an Python-idomatic way of doing this; using empty dicts as the default to `get()` and using anonymous functions both seem like good idioms.

Comment: Even though this answers the OP's question, I consider jpp's answer more concise. Raising a `KeyError` in some situations is more natural than returning an empty dict. Also, jpp's answer is more generic as it can be used for nested dictionaries, nested lists and mixtures of both.

Comment: This covers most cases, but a downside is that the usual test of `if d.get(k) is None` doesn't work anymore since this implementation doesn't distinguish a key pointing to an empty dict vs. a key which cannot be found

Answer (score 29):

[@ThomasOrozco's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225747/9209546) is correct, but resorts to a `lambda` function, which is only necessary to avoid `TypeError` if an intermediary key does *not* exist. If this isn't a concern, you can use `dict.get` directly:

```
from functools import reduce

def get_from_dict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(dict.get, mapList, dataDict)
```

Here's a demo:

```
a = {'Alice': {'Car': {'Color': 'Blue'}}}  
path = ['Alice', 'Car', 'Color']
get_from_dict(a, path)  # 'Blue'
```

---

If you wish to be more explicit than using `lambda` while still avoiding `TypeError`, you can wrap in a `try` / `except` clause:

```
def get_from_dict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    try:
        return reduce(dict.get, mapList, dataDict)
    except TypeError:
        return None  # or some other default value
```

---

Finally, if you wish to raise `KeyError` when a key does not exist at any level, use `operator.getitem` or `dict.__getitem__`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def getitem_from_dict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(getitem, mapList, dataDict)
    # or reduce(dict.__getitem__, mapList, dataDict)
```

Note that `[]` is syntactic sugar for the `__getitem__` method. So this relates precisely how you would ordinarily access a dictionary value. The `operator` module just provides a more readable means of accessing this method.

Comment: Note that this works perfectly also for nested lists. The variant using `getitem` will raise an `IndexError` if any of the indices is out of range.

Comment: Even better, the suggested answer can be used for dicts containing both nested lists and nested dicts, which is useful when working for example with json data.

Comment: ...I forgot to mention tuples and any object that implements the `__getitem__` method...

Comment: This also seem to work for `pandas`, although the exact allowed syntax for slicing a data frame is not clear to me....

Answer (score 4):

You can actually achieve this really neatly in Python 3, given its handling of default keyword arguments and tuple decomposition:

```
In [1]: def recursive_get(d, *args, default=None):
   ...:     if not args:
   ...:         return d
   ...:     key, *args = args
   ...:     return recursive_get(d.get(key, default), *args, default=default)
   ...:
```

Similar code will also work in python 2, but you'd need to revert to using `**kwargs`, as you did in your example.  You'd also need to use indexing to decompose `*args`.

In any case, there's no need for a loop if you're going to make the function recursive anyway.

You can see that the above code demonstrates the same functionality as your existing method:

```
In [2]: d = {'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}

In [3]: recursive_get(d, 'foo')
Out[3]: {'bar': 'baz'}

In [4]: recursive_get(d, 'foo', 'bar')
Out[4]: 'baz'

In [5]: recursive_get(d, 'bogus key', default='nonexistent key')
Out[5]: 'nonexistent key'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a defaultdict to give you an empty dict on missing keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(dict)
```

This only goes one level deep - `mydict[missingkey]` is an empty dict, `mydict[missingkey][missing key]` is a KeyError. You can add as many levels as needed by wrapping it in more `defaultdict`s, eg `defaultdict(defaultdict(dict))`. You could also have the innermost one as another defaultdict with a sensible factory function for your use case, eg

```
mydict = defaultdict(defaultdict(lambda: 'big summer blowout'))
```

If you need it to go to arbitrary depth, you can do that like so:

```
def insanity():
    return defaultdict(insanity)

print(insanity()[0][0][0][0])
```

Comment: How would you use this concept in a `recursive_get()` function?

Answer (score 0):

There is none that I am aware of. However, you don't need to subclass dict at all, you can just write a function that takes a dictionary, args and kwargs and does the same thing:

```
 def recursive_get(d, *args, **kwargs):
     default = kwargs.get('default')
     cursor = d
     for a in args:
         if cursor is default: break
         cursor = recursive_get(cursor, a, default)
     return cursor
```

use it like this

```
recursive_get(d, 'foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Your example raises `RecursionError`

Answer (score 0):

The OP requested the following behavior

```py
>>> d.recursive_get('bogus key', default='nonexistent key')
'nonexistent key'
```

(As of June 15, 22022) none of the up-voted answers accomplish this, so I have modified [@ThomasOrozco's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225747/7446465) to resolve this

```py
from functools import reduce

def rget(d, *keys, default=None):
    """Use a sentinel to handle both missing keys AND alternate default values"""
    sentinel = {}
    v = reduce(lambda c, k: c.get(k, sentinel), keys, d)
    if v is sentinel:
        return default
    return v
```

Below is a complete, unit-test-like demonstration of where the other answers have issues. I've named each approach according to its author. Note that this answer is the only one which passes all 4 test cases, namely

1. Basic retrieval when key-tree exists
2. Non-existent key-tree returns `None`
3. Option to specify a default aside from `None`
4. Values which are an empty dict should return as themselves rather than the default

```py
from functools import reduce


def thomas_orozco(d, *keys):
    return reduce(lambda c, k: c.get(k, {}), keys, d)


def jpp(dataDict, *mapList):
    """Same logic as thomas_orozco but exits at the first missing key instead of last"""
    try:
        return reduce(dict.get, *mapList, dataDict)
    except TypeError:
        return None


def sapi(d, *args, default=None):
    if not args:
        return d
    key, *args = args
    return sapi(d.get(key, default), *args, default=default)


def rget(d, *keys, default=None):
    sentinel = {}
    v = reduce(lambda c, k: c.get(k, sentinel), keys, d)
    if v is sentinel:
        return default
    return v


def assert_rget_behavior(func):
    """Unit tests for desired behavior of recursive dict.get()"""
    fail_count = 0

    # Basic retrieval when key-tree exists
    d = {'foo': {'bar': 'baz', 'empty': {}}}
    try:
        v = func(d, 'foo', 'bar')
        assert v == 'baz', f'Unexpected value {v} retrieved'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Case 1: Failed basic retrieval with {repr(e)}')
        fail_count += 1

    # Non-existent key-tree returns None
    try:
        v = func(d, 'bogus', 'key')
        assert v is None, f'Missing key retrieved as {v} instead of None'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Case 2: Failed missing retrieval with {repr(e)}')
        fail_count += 1

    # Option to specify a default aside from None
    default = 'alternate'
    try:
        v = func(d, 'bogus', 'key', default=default)
        assert v == default, f'Missing key retrieved as {v} instead of {default}'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Case 3: Failed default retrieval with {repr(e)}')
        fail_count += 1

    # Values which are an empty dict should return as themselves rather than the default
    try:
        v = func(d, 'foo', 'empty')
        assert v == {}, f'Empty dict value retrieved as {v} instead of {{}}'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Case 4: Failed retrieval of empty dict value with {repr(e)}')
        fail_count += 1

    # Success only if all pass
    if fail_count == 0:
        print('Passed all tests!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    assert_rget_behavior(thomas_orozco)  # Fails cases 2 and 3
    assert_rget_behavior(jpp)  # Fails cases 1, 3, and 4
    assert_rget_behavior(sapi)  # Fails cases 2 and 3

    assert_rget_behavior(rget)  # Only one to pass all 3
```

Comment: I mean, strictly speaking, the actual request in my question was whether there is a module which does roughly what I asked for: "Is there some built-in method that has equivalent or similar behavior? If not, are there any standard or external modules that provide this behavior?"  So the fact that none of the code in the other answers exactly matches the example usage in the question is not a problem as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

`softy` provides a readable interface for this.

```
import softy
d = softy.soften({'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}})

if d.foo.bar is not softy.null:
    print(f'd.foo.bar is {d.foo.bar}')
else:
    print('Nope, not there')

as_dict = softy.harden(d)
```

https://pypi.org/project/softy/

Disclaimer: I am the author of `softy`

Answer (score -1):

[collections.default_dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will handle the providing of default values for nonexistent keys at least.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to make it recursive.

Comment: So will `dict.get()`.  That's not the behavior I'm concerned with here.

Comment: @jayhendren see my answer.  I've debugged those functions and they're now used in production.  Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842260/7076615

Answer (score -1):

**The Iterative Solution**

```
def deep_get(d:dict, keys, default=None, create=True):
    if not keys:
        return default
    
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key in d:
            d = d[key]
        elif create:
            d[key] = {}
            d = d[key]
        else:
            return default
    
    key = keys[-1]
    
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    elif create:
        d[key] = default
    
    return default


def deep_set(d:dict, keys, value, create=True):
    assert(keys)
    
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key in d:
            d = d[key]
        elif create:
            d[key] = {}
            d = d[key]
    
    d[keys[-1]] = value 
    return value
```

I am about to test it inside of a Django project with a line such as:

```
keys = ('options', 'style', 'body', 'name')

val = deep_set(d, keys, deep_get(s, keys, 'dotted'))
```