# How to return nested dictionary from function

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a function that will return a nested dict depending on the arguments?

```
def foo(key):
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
    return d[key]

foo(['c']['d'])
```

I waiting for:

```
3
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I understanding that it possible to return a whole dict, or hard code it to return a particular part of dict, like

```
if 'c' and 'd' in kwargs:
    return d['c']['d']
elif 'c' and 'e' in kwargs:
        return d['c']['e']
```

but it will be very inflexible

Comment: Kindly check this link: [Is there a recursive version of the dict.get() built-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225552/is-there-a-recursive-version-of-the-dict-get-built-in). The error you're getting is due to this expression- `['c']['d']`, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give `['c']['d']`, you slice the list `['c']` using the letter `d`, which isin't possible. So what you can do is, correct the slicing:

```
foo('c')['d']
```

Or you could alter your function to slice it:

```
def foo(*args):
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
    d_old = dict(d) # if case you have to store the dict for other operations in the fucntion
    for i in args:
        d = d[i]
    return d
>>> foo('c','d')
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
def funt(keys):
  val = d
  for key in keys:
    if val:
      val = val.get(key)
  return val

funt(['c', 'd'])
```

Additionally to handle key not present state.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution would be to iterate over multiple keys -

```
def foo(keys, d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 3, 'e': 4}, }
    if len(keys) == 1:
        return d[keys[0]]
    return foo(keys[1:], d[keys[0]])

foo(['c', 'd'])
```

Comment: This is an extremely wrong way to copy dictionaries

Comment: I don't actually want to copy a dictionary, but that gave me an idea for a fix

Comment: also this code doesnt work, if the dictionary is more nested