# Problem parsing JSON converted to text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some JSON to get some values, for example the value of 'Count'. I can successfully retrieve the JSON and convert it to text but .get() returns 'NONE' for any values I try to get. The code I am using is:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = 'https://irus.jisc.ac.uk/api/sushilite/v1_7/GetReport/?Report=IR1&Release=4&RequestorID=Cambridge&BeginDate=2020-01&EndDate=2020-05&ItemIdentifier=irusuk%3A1861749&Granularity=Monthly&Pretty=Pretty'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
site_json=json.loads(soup.text)
x = site_json.get('Count')
print(x)
```

Comment: 'Count' is in inner dictionary you can't get that by just using `site_json.get('Count')`. You have to use full path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a recursive version of the dict.get() built-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225552/is-there-a-recursive-version-of-the-dict-get-built-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the `JSON`

```
try:
    for values in site_json["ReportResponse"]["Report"]["Report"]["Customer"]["ReportItems"][0]["ItemPerformance"]:
        print(values["Instance"]["Count"])
except KeyError as e:
    print("Key not found" , e)
```

**Another approach:**

if `ReportItems` key having multiple values in the list. You can simply iterate the value from `ReportItems` key.

```
try:
    for values in site_json["ReportResponse"]["Report"]["Report"]["Customer"]["ReportItems"]:
        for performance in values["ItemPerformance"]:
            print(performance["Instance"]["Count"])
except KeyError as e:
    print("Key not found" , e)
```

Output:

```
1001
6273
2128
993
1365
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I figured it had been converted to text so didn't think to parse the JSON. Relatively new to Python so apologies if this was a stupid question.

Comment: A quick follow up question: why is the '[0]' necessary in this code?

Comment: @tmnsnmt `["ReportItems"]` key having a value as `list`. So taking the first `index` of the value from the `list`. You can iterate the `["ReportItems"]` as well if list having multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating of the JSON object
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

```
url = 'https://irus.jisc.ac.uk/api/sushilite/v1_7/GetReport/?Report=IR1&Release=4&RequestorID=Cambridge&BeginDate=2020-01&EndDate=2020-05&ItemIdentifier=irusuk%3A1861749&Granularity=Monthly&Pretty=Pretty'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
site_json=json.loads(soup.text)
for itemIdentifier in  site_json["ReportResponse"]["Report"]["Report"]['Customer']["ReportItems"]:
    for itemPerformance in itemIdentifier["ItemPerformance"]:
        print(itemPerformance["Instance"]["Count"])
```

Output all the counts

```
1001
6273
2128
993
1365
```

In this nested loops you will be able to make some logic of getting a specific count our all of the counts.