# Passing dict to try except function to check if value exist

Tags: python, dictionary, try-except

Please I need help, I have to check if some values exist in dictionary so I have multiple try except statements.
So, what I'm thinking is to write a function that takes the dict and checks if that value exist or not (if it didn't exist will return None) but the problem is when I call that function with dict as parameter it gives error since that field doesn;t exits. So here is what I did so far but is giving error in main function:

```
def main():
  return_value = test(dict["one"]["two"])

And here is the test function:

def test(value):
  try:
    one = value
  except:
    one = None
  finally:
    return one
```

Comment: The problem is you aren't passing a dictionary to your function. You *doing `dict["one"]["two"]`* which gets *evaluated first*, and the result of that is actually passed to your function. Since `dict["one"]["two"]` throws an error, your function is never actually invoked. And note, `one = value` would never throw an error anyway. You have a fundamental misconception of how Python evaluates arguments. Some languages actually work how you assumed it would, that evaluation strategy is "call  by name", but Python doesn't use that

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if a value exists as a key in a dictionary , simply do this:

```
value in dict
```

Example:

```
d = { 4 : "exists"}

assert 4 in d
assert 5 not in d
```

If you want a default value, you can use get:

```
v = d.get(5, "mydefault")
assert v == "mydefault"
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a dict nested inside list so that won't work

Comment: update your question example dictionary you have

Comment: I added dict["one"]["two"] so I need to check if that data exist or not

Comment: Not just a key in dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `get()` from dict.
It will return `None` if your dict does not have the key.

```
return_value = dict.get("one")
# return_value is equal to None if "one" is not in the dict
```

Comment: How I can change that if I want to check not just the key "one" l want to check ["one"]["two"] is in dict?

Comment: You can see answers to this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225552/is-there-a-recursive-version-of-the-dict-get-built-in

Comment: ohh thanks that is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you agian :)