# How to modify the last node of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Consider that you have a nested dictionary as the following:

```py
{
    "text": "hi",
    "next": {
        "text": "hi",
        "next": {
            "text": "hi",
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the last node to `{"text": "bye"}`, so that my end result is as follows:

```py
{
    "text": "hi",
    "next": {
        "text": "hi",
        "next": {
            "text": "bye",
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that there can be thousands of nodes but I want to modify just the last node. How can I do it?

Comment: Thousands ? You will have [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) then.

Comment: I am not writing it in python but i want the solution in python so that i can understand the concept

Comment: @keepAlive Only if they do it in a simple recursive way.

Comment: sorry i forgot the ```,```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through dictionary, getting last object and changing it

```py
d = {
"text":"hi",
"next":{
        "text":"hi",
        "next":{
                "text":"bye"
                  }
}
}

pre = d
while True:
    next_ = pre.get('next')
    if not next_:
        pre['text'] = 'bye'
        break
    pre = next_
print(d)
```

Comment: This is not a recursive solution.

Comment: @keepAlive So what?

Comment: What is the title of the question @Kelly ? Ah no... ***You are right***... I read too fast.

Comment: Dictionary is recursive, they dont require  recursion,

Comment: @keepAlive That they have a recursive *dictionary* structure. Not that they want a recursive solution.

Comment: I need to access 'next' value in pre, so i use get, since it also checks if exist by returning vALUE OR NONE

Answer (score 1):

if you know the depth of the dictionary, you can use `reduce` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225552):

```
from functools import reduce
def reduce_dict(data, items):
    return reduce(dict.get, items, data)
depth = 1000
reduce_dict(my_dict, ['next']* depth)['text'] = 'bye'
```

Comment: If we have the depth, we might also have the tail and just do `tail['text'] = 'bye'` :-)

Comment: Depending on how you are collecting the information, it is not uncommon to be provided with the constraints of the input (here the depth) to properly process the data. Having `tail`, while convenient is not that common.

Answer (score 1):

```
root = {'text': 'hi', 'next': {'text': 'hi', 'next': {'text': 'hi'}}}

node = root
while 'next' in node:
    node = node['next']
node['text'] = 'bye'

print(root)
```

Output:

```
{'text': 'hi', 'next': {'text': 'hi', 'next': {'text': 'bye'}}}
```