# Dictionary variables and "for" loop

Tags: python

I am trying to pull out some specific values from this output:

```
{'GigabitEthernet': [{'name': '1', 'ip': {'address': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.200.200', 'mask': '255.255.255.0'}}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf': {'ospf': {'authentication': {'key-chain': 'sv-10599'}, 'message-digest-key': [{'id': 1, 'md5': {'auth-key': 'cisco'}}], 'network': {'point-to-point': [None]}}}}, 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '2', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '3', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}]}
```

Ideally I would like to get the following values:

GigabitEthernet 1  192.168.200.200

GigabitEthernet 2  Shutdown
     # determine interface IP addresses

```
 for interface_type_gig in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']['GigabitEthernet']:
    interface_name = 'GigabitEthernet ' + interface_type_gig['name']
    print(interface_name)
    interface_address = interface_type_gig['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
    print(interface_address)
```

I am able to get the ['name'] but not the IP address. Interface_address returns a `KeyError: 1`

I am  not able to get figure out.

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback as properly formatted text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing value inside nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399614/accessing-value-inside-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: There are two dictionaries. In the second one there is no 'ip' key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested dictionary. I can only assume as to what the full dataset looks like. Assuming if the `ip` key is present, you have the ip addresss, and if not present it's `Shutdown`, you can just check for that and iterate that way:

```
data = {'GigabitEthernet': [{'name': '1', 'ip': {'address': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.200.200', 'mask': '255.255.255.0'}}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf': {'ospf': {'authentication': {'key-chain': 'sv-10599'}, 'message-digest-key': [{'id': 1, 'md5': {'auth-key': 'cisco'}}], 'network': {'point-to-point': [None]}}}}, 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '2', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '3', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}]}

for interface_type_gig in data['GigabitEthernet']:
    interface_name = 'GigabitEthernet ' + interface_type_gig['name']

    if 'ip' in interface_type_gig.keys():
        interface_address = interface_type_gig['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
    else:
        interface_address = 'Shutdown'

    print(interface_name)
    print(interface_address)
```