# How to access an element inside a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python

How to access an element inside a nested dictionary in python?

```
    myfamily = {
      "child1" : {
        "name" : "Emil",
        "year" : 2004
      },
      "child2" : {
        "name" : "Tobias",
        "year" : 2007
      },
      "child3" : {
        "name" : "Linus",
        "year" : 2011
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing value inside nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399614/accessing-value-inside-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily access a child by using `myfamily["child1"]` 
You can also access all keys by calling the `keys()` method on the `myfamily` variable

Answer (score 1):

Indexing `myfamily` yields another `dict`, which you index like any other.

```
>>> myfamily["child1"]["name"]
'Emil'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat sub dictionaries just like a new dictionary

```
myfamily['child1']['year']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to access the elements of `myfamily`, you can refer to those as `myfamily['child1']`, and that will return:

```
{
    "name" : "Emil",
    "year" : 2004
}
```

If `child1` was its own directory, you were refer to elements in that as `child1['name']` or `child1['year']`. Extending that to `myfamily['child1']`, you can access elements in `child1` by identifying the element you want, like `myfamily['child1']['name']` or `myfamily['child1']['year']`.

Why doesn't `myfamily[child1['name']]` work? If we separate our pieces, `child1['name']` contains `Emil`. Substitute that for `child1['name']` in `myfamily[child1['name']]`, and we have `myfamily['Emil']`. That element doesn't exist in the `myfamily` dictionary, and will fail.